# Perl: How do I split AND cut a given String?

Tags: mysql, perl, split, cut

I have a String that looks like this:

$string = "Tags: sweet, yummie, chocolate, dark"

I want to insert these Tags in a Mysql table.

- So how do I cut the [Tags:] out of the string?
- And how can I add foreach $string in a Mysql-table?

Answer (score 3):

Start by removing the "Tags: " with a regex, and then split on ", ".

```
my $string = "Tags: sweet, yummie, chocolate, dark"
$string =~ s/Tags: //;
my @tags = split /, /, @string;
```

For the MySQL connection, you could use DBI::MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`split` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) in Perl.

> The `split` function is used to split a string into smaller sections. You can split a string on a single character, a group of characers or a regular expression (a pattern).
>
> You can also specify how many pieces to split the string into.

Answer (score 0):

If your Tags always end with column `:`,
you could do somethong like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dumper;

my $string = "Tags: sweet, yummie, chocolate, dark";
my @parts = split/[:,]\s*/,$string;
say Dumper \@parts;
```

**output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Tags',
          'sweet',
          'yummie',
          'chocolate',
          'dark'
        ];
```